# Adding the same items to multiple comboboxes

Tags: c#

I have 30 comboboxes and in each one of them I have to add the same items. Is there a faster way to do this than typing the same code all over again for 30 times?

```
        comboBox1.Items.Add("K");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("H");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("L");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("T");
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

        comboBox2.Items.Add("K");
        comboBox2.Items.Add("H");
        comboBox2.Items.Add("L");
        comboBox2.Items.Add("T");
        comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

... and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] values = new[] { "K", "H", "L", "T" };
foreach(string value in values) 
{
    combobox1.Items.Add(value);
    combobox2.Items.Add(value);
}
```

Even better, if the ItemsCollection has an AddRange method:

```
string[] values = new[] { "K", "H", "L", "T" };
combobox1.Items.AddRange(values);
combobox2.Items.AddRange(values);
```

Comment: Why -1? Seriously, I'm new here.

Comment: At least WinForms ComboBox has AddRange method for Items. So I like this solution. But you also need to set selected index

Comment: Yes, I added selected index for each combobox and it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: You still need to repeat the code for 30 comboboxes! Ouch!!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over all comboboxes using `OfType` method:

```
int i = 0;
foreach(var cmbBox in this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
{
    cmbBox.Items.Add("K");
    cmbBox.Items.Add("H");
    cmbBox.Items.Add("L");
    cmbBox.Items.Add("T");
    cmbBox.SelectedIndex = i++;
}
```

Comment: If comboboxes added to Controls collection not in ascending order of their names, then incorrect indexes will be selected

Comment: That's not right, but actually we have to been told the rule for the SelectedIndex! So `i` is probably wrong anyway..

Answer (score 1):

```
InitComboBox(comboBox1);
InitComboBox(comboBox2);
...


private void InitComboBox(ComboBox cb)
{
    cb.Items.Add("K");
    cb.Items.Add("H");
    cb.Items.Add("L");
    cb.Items.Add("T");
    cb.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You add a method `FillCombo`

```
void FillCombo(Control ctrl)
{
    foreach (ComboBox cb in ctrl.Controls) 
    {
     cb.Items.Add("K");
    cb.Items.Add("H");
    cb.Items.Add("L");
    cb.Items.Add("T");
    cb.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

To use it :

```
FillCombo(this);
```